# How to write user defined function in pandas for outliers

Tags: python, pandas, outliers

Suppose I have a data frame

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame()
data["name"] = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"]
data["age"] = [22,9,505,39,50,17,26,33,-43,48]
data["marks"] = [422,59,75,3,50,47,2,83,63,48]
data
```

Now I want to remove all the outliers from the numeric variables. I can do that using the 1.5+- IQR formula.

```
Q1 = data.age.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = data.age.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
d=data.loc[~((data.age < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (data.age > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))),]
d
```

I want to create an user defined function so that I can put the name of the variable and automatically the outliers should be removed. I had tried to write an user defined function:

```
def outlier (data,age):
 Q1 = data.age.quantile(0.25)
 Q3 = data.age.quantile(0.75)
 IQR = Q3 - Q1
 data.loc[~((data.age < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (data.age > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))),]
 return data



outlier(data,marks)
```

However, it's saying the marks is not defined. Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Where is the variable `marks` defined in your code, you are using it on `outlier(data, marks)` function call.

Answer (score 2):

As error suggests `marks` is not defined in your code. You need to pass `marks` as `str`

eg. `outlier(data, "marks")`

You need to make changes in your function too, to use different columns

```
def outlier(data, col):
   Q1 = data[col].quantile(0.25)
   Q3 = data[col].quantile(0.75)
   IQR = Q3 - Q1
   data = data.loc[~((data[col] < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (data[col] > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))),]
   return data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by calculating z-scores:

```py
import pandas as pd

def zscore(x):
    """Calculate Z Score."""
    return (x - x.mean()) / x.std()

def remove_outliers(data: pd.DataFrame, column):
    """Remove outliers."""
    # calculate z-score and set nans to 0
    zscores = zscore(data[column])
    zscores[zscores.isnull()] = 0
    return data.iloc[zscores[(-2 < zscores) & (zscores < 2)].index]

data = pd.DataFrame()
data["name"] = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"]
data["age"] = [22,9,505,39,50,17,26,33,-43,48]
data["marks"] = [422,59,75,3,50,47,2,83,63,48]

print(remove_outliers(data, "age"))
```

Output:

```
  name  age  marks
0    A   22    422
1    B    9     59
3    D   39      3
4    E   50     50
5    F   17     47
6    G   26      2
7    H   33     83
8    I  -43     63
9    J   48     48
```